# How do I use Octave with c++?

Tags: c++, octave

I'm using version 4.2.2.

I have a c++ program and I want to use Octave methods within c++.

And yes, I checked this link, but does not show in any step how to call functions of type imread, imshow or imhist. I can call octave.h or oct.h functions.

Simplifying the question. Is it possible to call octave imread within the c++ code?

As an example, in OpenCv I can do this:

```
  (c++ code)
  ...
  cv::Mat outImage; 
  outImage = cv::imread("rice.jpg"); 
  ...
  (c++ code)
```

Is there any way to do something like octave?

Comment: Q: What version of Octave are you using (6.3.0)?  Q: Have you looked here: https://octave.org/doc/v6.3.0/External-Code-Interface.html?  Q: Are you trying to call Octave from C++, or call C++ from Octave?  Please clarify your use case.

Comment: In particular have a look at https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Calling-Octave-Functions-from-Oct_002dFiles.html ( and presumably https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Standalone-Programs.html )

Comment: Yes, I checked this link, has a small part that shows an example. But with the information on this link I could not replicate with an image.